# Can having a lot of DBSets in the DbContext file affect performance?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework

We have a large number of tables (around 1800) in our MySQL database and most of the time, every developer creates their own project and adds a context with just the necessary tables as `DbSet`s. One of my colleagues suggested creating a single project that has every single table in the database and sharing it amongst every project. Could this affect performance? For instance, would it slow down the program at startup or during running credits?

Comment: A DbContext isn't a database model. It's a Unit-of-Work. It deals with *entities*, not tables. You'll never use 1800 different entites in a Unit of Work, which means what you describe is a clear design error. A DbContext contains the *entities* used in a use case. In DDD terms you'd say it contains the entities found in a bounded context

Comment: EF Core is an Object to Relational Mapper. It Maps Object entities to Relational constructs, it's not a database connection or model. Talking about DbSets as tables instead of entities is a clear indication that the ORM is misused.

Comment: The current situation is far better than the "fix" - every project has different requirements, different entities with different relations between them. It would be *very* hard to create a single Unit of Work or set of entities that could handle everything. You'd either end up with something nobody can use, or something that would change every time someone needed yet-another entity, or even a calculated property. Besides a database with 1800 table almost certainly has different areas that involve independently. It would make no sense to tightly couple eg order and marketing tables

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much. So we had a discussion on the team and decided against it. Mainly because of the reasons you mentioned here too. But I'm still curious. Would it slow things down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large DbContexts can be slower to initialize, which is a one-off cost when the `DbContext` is first used. This is also when a `DbContext` might fail due to an invalid schema configuration. You can "warm" the `DbContext` by issuing a simple query when your service/application starts up. For instance:

```
// Check application DB version and warm the DbContext.
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var dbVersion = context.AppConfig.Select(x => x.DbVersion).Single();
    if (dbVersion < MinimumDbVersion)
       throw new ApplicationException("The application database version is too low.");
}
```

Where the database has an AppConfig table containing config settings including a DbVersion. Basically it can be anything, loading config settings, or simply doing a `Count` of Users or such. As long as a query executes, the DbContext's static initialization will execute.

The length of time needed to initialize isn't really linked to the `DbSet` declarations as much as it is linked to the number of entities in total that the `DbContext` needs to be aware of. Even if you have 100 "top-level" entities with a `DbSet` defined for them, if those entities span out to reveal relationships to another 1700 entities then that will be effectively the same amount of work as 1800 DbSets.

Bounded contexts are a process where you split up entities into "contexts" where each `DbContext` serves a key area of a system. This both reduces the number of entities that each `DbContext` needs to know about, speeding up initialization, but it also helps better organize your code to focus on entities, and even representations of the underlying data that is relevant to that area. Entities can be shared between `DbContext` instances, though you should seek to ensure that only one `DbContext` is responsible for writing that entity. For instance you might define separate `DbContext` instances for managing Customers and managing Orders. Orders need to know about their customers, but it would be the CustomerDbContext's responsibility to create/update customer information, not the OrderDbContext. One option there is to use something like a CustomerSummary entity within the OrderDbContext to map just the essential details of a customer when in the context of an order. Ideally the DbContext should be inspecting what entity types are present in the inserted/updated/deleted change tracker on SaveChanges and throw exceptions if anything other than the entity types they are responsible for show up there.

The typical performance killer for DbContext's that is typically blamed on their size is generally allowing DbContext instances to live too long and track too many entities. The more entities that a DbContext knows about, the easier it is for them to end up tracking a lot more entities without the developers realizing the instances are open too long. There is an assumption that a bigger context is "more expensive" to create, so it gets opened and passed around/persisted longer to avoid that perceived cost, which incurs performance costs from that instance gradually getting bloated by tracked instances.